# Suppose $B$ is a set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a family of sets. If $\cup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B $ then $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathbb{P}(B)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, notation, proof-explanation

I don’t quite understand why the empty set is not considered in the proof of the theorem.

The proof I have come across is:

Suppose $\cup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}$. Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $x$. Since $y \in x$ and $x \in \mathcal{F}$, clearly $y \in \cup \mathcal{F}$. But then since $\cup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$, $y \in B$. Since $y$ was an arbitrary element of $x$, we can conclude that $x \subseteq B$, so $x\in \mathbb{P} (B)$. But $x$ was an arbitrary element of $\mathcal{F}$, so this shows that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathbb{P} (B)$, as required.

The main question I have is with the statement:
‘Let $y$ be an arbitrary element of $x$’ implies that the set $x$ is non-empty but isn’t $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F}$?

The other question is regarding the notation of sets. Throughout the book sets have been indicated by capital letters and elements of sets using lower case letters. Why would the author use $x$ to represent an arbitrary set (element) of $\mathcal{F}$? Are there general guidelines for choosing variables?

Comment: Recall that to prove that $A\subseteq B$, the standard phrasing of the proof is to prove the implication "**If** $x\in A$ then $x\in B$, therefore $A\subseteq B$"  In the event that no such $x$ exists in the first place, then that just makes the hypothesis in the implication false, making the implication itself vacuously true.

Comment: Could this have been phrased perhaps a bit better?  Sure... Just put phrases like "Suppose without loss of generality that $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty" or "Suppose without loss of generality that $x$ is non-empty" etc... and discuss the cases where $\mathcal{F}$ and/or $x$ are empty separately.

Comment: As for guidelines for naming variables... they can all be ignored at a whim at the author's discretion, however it is *common* (*though I must stress by no means required*) to have families of sets written with `\mathscr` or `\mathcal` such as $\mathcal{F}$, to have sets containing what might as well be [urelements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Urelement) written in uppercase, and to have what might as well be urelements written in lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write the same proof as follows :

Let $F$ be any element of $\mathcal{F}$.

[it makes more sense expositionally to have sets be capitals, families of sets use `\mathcal` font etc., elements small letters etc. But that's just convention.]

If $F = \emptyset$, $F \in \Bbb P(B)$ trivially and we're done. 
[this step is not strictly necessary, see below, but could be added]

Let $x \in F$ be arbitrary, then $x \in \bigcup \mathcal{F} \subseteq B$ so $x \in B$ and hence $F \subseteq B$.

[This would also have worked for the empty set, which is a subset of any set we like. Void truth etc.]

Hence $F \in \Bbb P(B)$ and the inclusion has been shown.

But be flexible in what you accept as notations, the proof you gave using $x$ as element of $\mathcal{F}$ might be confusing at first, but in set theory everything is a set, so distinguishing different levels of abstraction is not as important.